# python 3.x discord.py Music Bot - How to make music queue that can be played in multiple servers

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code for a python discord bot and it works well for queuing music in one server, but when multiple servers are using it, it waits until the first requested song is done before playing the next one in the other server. I would like to get it so that it will be able to play multiple songs in multiple servers.

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
songs = asyncio.Queue()
play_next_song = asyncio.Event()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')


async def audio_player_task():
    while True:
        play_next_song.clear()
        current = await songs.get()
        current.start()
        await play_next_song.wait()


def toggle_next():
    client.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(play_next_song.set)


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not client.is_voice_connected(ctx.message.server):
        voice = await client.join_voice_channel(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
    else:
        voice = client.voice_client_in(ctx.message.server)

    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(url, after=toggle_next)
    await songs.put(player)

client.loop.create_task(audio_player_task())

client.run('token')
```

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/playlist.py

Answer (score 2):

Make a dictionary and set key as server.id and value as songs.
Like this :

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
songs = asyncio.Queue()
play_next_song = asyncio.Event()
queues = {} #new dictionary

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')


async def audio_player_task():
    while True:
        play_next_song.clear()
        current = await queues[id].get()
        current.start()
        await play_next_song.wait()

def toggle_next():
    client.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(play_next_song.set)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    ctx.message.server = server
    queues[server.id] = songs
    ...
```

And when u append new songs, 
do like this : await queues[server.id].put(player)